# How to filter an array containing a string and an array of structure objects, in which there is a string parameter?

Tags: arrays, swift, filter, swift4

I have an array

```
var friendsListGroupedFiltered = [Object]()
```

of this structure

```
struct Object {
    var letters : String
    var sectionObjects : [Friend]
}
```

that contains an array of objects of another structure

```
struct Friend {
    let name: String
    let image: UIImage?
    let likes: Int
    let isLiked: Bool
}
extension Friend: Equatable {
    static func == (lhs: Friend, rhs: Friend) -> Bool {
        return lhs.name == rhs.name
    }
}
```

And to be precise, I want to make a filter function for searchbar.
I tried like this

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, textDidChange searchText: String) {
    guard !searchText.isEmpty else {
        friendsListGroupedFiltered = friendsListGrouped
        tableView.reloadData()
        return
    }
    friendsListGroupedFiltered = friendsListGroupedFiltered.filter {
        $0.sectionObjects.filter {
            $0.name.range (of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
        }
    }
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

and get an error

> Cannot convert value of type '[Friend]' to closure result type 'Bool'

array friendsListGroupedFiltered looks something like this

```
[Object(
    letters: "А",
    sectionObjects: [
        Friend(name: "Августин", image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600000d3ab50>, {200, 200}), likes: 20, isLiked: false),
        Friend(name: "Акакий", image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600000d3ab50>, {200, 200}), likes: 20, isLiked: false),
        Friend(name: "Алёша", image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600000d3ab50>, {200, 200}), likes: 20, isLiked: false),
        Friend(name: "Армэн", image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600000d3ab50>, {200, 200}), likes: 20, isLiked: false)
    ]
),
Object(
    letters: "В",
    sectionObjects: [
        Friend(name: "Вася", image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600000d3ab50>, {200, 200}), likes: 20, isLiked: false)
    ]
),
Object(
    letters: "К",
    sectionObjects: [
        Friend(name: "Коловрат", image: Optional(<UIImage: 0x600000d3ab50>, {200, 200}), likes: 20, isLiked: false)
    ]
)
```

etc
How can I sort an array by 'name' that is contained within another array of objects of another structure?

Comment: use `.contains` instead of `.filter` doesn't fit, because it return all array `[Friend]` by letter. I need to receive `[Object]` with only those `Friend` that contain the entered text

Answer (score 0):

The result of `filter` is the array of filtered objects (`[Friend]`) but the result of the filtering closure is a `Bool`.

That's what the error message tells you.

You could check if the filtered array is not empty but better is `contains`

```
friendsListGroupedFiltered = friendsListGrouped.filter {
    $0.sectionObjects.contains {
        $0.name.range (of: searchText, options: .caseInsensitive) != nil
    }
}
```

Comment: `!sequence.filter(predicate).isEmpty` is better expressed as `sequence.contains(where: predicate)`

Comment: if I use '$0.sectionObjects.contains', I get the entire array with the letter "A", with the text entered, for example, "Авг". Array [Friend] is not filtered. I need to receive only those Friend that contain the entered text

Comment: The result of `filter` is an array of the same type. You cannot filter `Object` to `Friend`.